# Will upgrading the class of the DB instance speed up my lambda application

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a Django application that is connected to a PostgreSQL database located on AWS RDS.

Right now, because it's still in development we use a small tier (db.t3.small) which has 2vCPUs, 2GiB RAM and 2.085 Mbps.

My application is running smooth and fast, except for one model because it has over 6 million rows.
It takes about 25 seconds to load even when working on localhost. 
When I then switch to a local postgreSQL database on my computer with the same data it takes around 3s to load

So I'm wondering, if I upgrade to db.t3.medium or even db.t3.large that both double in RAM size from his previous tier. will this make any diffrence in speed for my application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very hard to tell with limited amount of information:

However: Check your RDS graphs, see a load spike? Then upscale might help. It could however be that the loadspike was too short for cloudwatch to notice.

The easiest solution would be to just try. An upscale only takes a couple of minutes and you can always just downscale again if you did not receive the desired effect.

Comment: Well, trial and error was the method. It goes 5sec faster going from a small (2GiB) to a medium 4(GiB). So I guess when out of development we could move to a higher tier